# Help needed: identify hubs TRW 9000

Tags: hub

[image][image]I bought this old randoneering frame

It came with TRW 9000 hubs. I've done lots of web searches but couldn't find anything.

Has anyone out there seen them before or know anything about them?

Cheers,

Cormac

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm not sure what you're asking about here.  You have the part number (TRW 9000), what else do you need to know?

Comment: Maybe he wants to know what year or era they were manufactured, whether they are easily serviceable or not, compatible or not with modern components, how rare they are, etc. Literally any additional info. The question is broad, but can be answered, and may provide useful information to other people too. Unfortunately I know nothing about that model.

Comment: Hi Criggie, DavidW & Robert - thanks for the help. In terms of what I'm looking for you summed it up perfectly  Robert! I added a photo of the front hub.

Answer (score 2):

Nice pictures.
The hubs seem to be of good quality, definitely not what you would find on a BSO ("bicycle shaped object" as they are called, i.e a bicycle found in a general goods store, with cheaply manufactured components). The bearings seem to be nicely sealed. They shouldn't have any play. If they do have play, you can find good tutorials online about how to adjust them, and can ask more questions here as well. Or get them to a bike shop, it's an easy task for them.

I see the yellow Mavic logo on the rim. That is a reputable brand of good quality wheels. Also the spoke holes appear to be eyeletted, i.e they have a reinforcement around the area that holds the spoke. That improves the durability of the wheel. If the bike was not crashed, the wheels should still be true.

Judging from the style of the [quick release levers](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/skewers.html), and the fact that there's no information about the hubs online, I would say this is an older model, before the year 2000 perhaps.

The rear hub most likely has a screwed on [freewheel](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/199/bicycle-rear-sprockets-freewheel-vs-freehub/) instead of a freehub + cassette. It seems to have 6 cogs, which was common a few decades ago. Nowadays bikes have up to 12 cogs in the back. A bike shop might be able to fetch a replacement if the cogs are worn. I would check the [chain wear](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/workshop/how-to-know-when-its-time-to-replace-your-bicycle-chain/) first. If it's less than 0.5% longer than its original length (chains get longer as they wear), and it doesn't slip/skip teeth under load, then is all good. If it's more than 1%, then the cogs might be too worn as well.

Since the wheels were made by Mavic, you could try emailing them asking for more information about the TRW 9000 hubs that they used to build these wheels.

To sum it up, they are old, but very nice wheels. And good bike shops should still be able to get them in good working condition, or find replacement parts, if needed.